# Airflow trigger_rule for grandparent tasks

Tags: airflow

I have following dag

```
task_a >> task_b>> task_c
```

`task_b` has `all_done` trigger rule

`task_c` has `all_success` trigger rule

if task a fails, will `task_c` will get executed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in that scenario `task_c` will be executed.

Trigger Rules consider the statuses of directly upstream tasks.
In your case the end result if `task_a` failed will be:

[image]

Explanation: `task_a` fails, `task_b` is executed because `task_a` is finished (due to `all_done` rule), `task_c` consider only `task_b` status which is `all_success` thus `task_c` can also run.

If you don't want `task_c` to be executed when `task_a` fails you need to define:

```
task_a >> task_b>> task_c
task_a >> task_c
```

Which will give:

[image]

in that scenario task_c is set to `upstream_failed`.

Comment: if task_a success but task_b failed. the task_c will run. what to do to prevent task_c from running in case any failed?

Comment: will task_c runs 2 times if task_a and task_b succeeds?

Comment: @Tula dependencies just set relations between tasks. Nothing more.