# How to set trigger_rule on specific tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow, orchestration

I would like to set trigger rules on specific tasks.

For instance, if i have the following dependencies in my dag :

`task_init >> task_1 >> task_2`

- task_init needs to be ok to run task_1
- task_2 can run only if task_init is ok but does not pay attention to task_2

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigger rules for what you're describing:

```py
task_init >> [task_1, task_2]
```

By default, tasks in Airflow run if the previous task completed successfully. So in this code, `task_init` starts, and tasks `task_1` and `task_2` only start after `task_init` completed successfully. A list (`[]`) can be used to group tasks together and dependencies can be set between a single task and a list of tasks.

You can also view this in the Airflow Graph View:

[image]

Read more about task dependencies here:

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#task-dependencies
- https://www.astronomer.io/guides/managing-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't mention it, but i would like to execute tasks sequentially. If i use [], task_1 and task_2 will be parallalized no ?

Comment: Correct. But if you want tasks to run sequentially, the code in your question works fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
task_init >> task_1 >> task_2
task_init >> task_2
```

This will resolve the problem. More information can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66866925